# mapping # in vim

Tags: vim, keymapping

In my .vimrc I have mapped the #-key to a macro for commenting out/in lines of code.

Unfortunately # in vim already has a function - it searches backwards for the word beneath the cursor.

What I would now like to have is a way to map this functionality to another key-sequence (ideally I would like to have Control-* for that as * alone searches forward).

Does anyone know how to achieve this?

Many thanks!

Comment: there are a few commenting plugins: `NERDCommenter`, which uses `<leader>c<space>` to toggle comment. the other one is `tComment`, that uses `gcc` for the same result.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>*</kbd> cannot be used; I would propose <kbd>\</kbd><kbd>*</kbd>; it's longer to type, but backwards searches are probably not that common.

```
:nnoremap <Leader>* #
```

Answer (score 0):

Like Ingo Karkat said, mapping Ctrl+certain keys is impossible in vim. However, you can map `Alt+8` instead:

```
noremap <A-8> #
```

I suggest `Alt+8` instead of `Alt+*` because if you wanted to bend your hand in unnatural ways to press more than one modifier keys to perform a command, you would probably be using Emacs instead of Vim.

Answer (score 0):

I use <kbd>\</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> for commenting and <kbd>\</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd> for removing comments. The mappings are following :

```
:map \c <ESC>:s,^\(\s*\)[^/ \t]\@=,\1// <ESC>,e<CR>j$a
:map \d <ESC>:s,^\(\s*\)// \s\@!,\1<ESC>,e<CR>j$a
```

Above mappings are used in command mode. Taken from one answer on SO, which I am currently unable to find.